# XSLT 3.0 Will streaming of 1000's small XML files improve performance?

Tags: saxon, xslt-3.0

I have a repository of circa 600K XML files and need to audit all the possible values of `<country name="Country_Name">` and these files are generally small, 80k max filesize.

`<country name="Country_Name">` is held in the metadata section of the XML near the top before the main body of the article, would using a streaming approach vastly improve the performance of the extracting the county value as streaming would be stopped as soon as that element was discovered by the Xpath?

Is this the right approach and if so, I'm running the Professional Edition of Saxon and would like to know if streaming lots of small documents warrants upgrading to Enterprise Edition.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:mode streamable="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-stream select="doc('file:///C:/temp/*.xml')">
      <xsl:value-of select="//country"/>
      <!-- Replace the following with your code to dump the current file -->
      <xsl:message select="concat('Processing ', document-uri(.))"/>
    </xsl:for-each-stream>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected A message of each printed to the screen.

Comment: Is `xsl:for-each-stream select="doc('file:///C:/temp/*.xml')"` an example you find in the XSLT 3 spec or any Saxon documentation of Saxon 10 or 11 or 12 on streaming?

Comment: Hello Martin,  
First an apology, I've been playing with the AI chat bot with PowerShell questions and getting half decent response so I pushed my luck with a XSLT 3 question.   The code above is its response.   I ran the code with Saxon and it failed with the error xsl:for-each-stream is not known.  But I also received the Warning " SXST0068: Request for streaming ignored: this Saxon configuration does not support streaming" so this was the reason for my question.

As a first time poster I had to answer the  "What have you tried before?" question and carelessly pasted in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use e.g.

```
<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
  <xsl:for-each select="uri-collection('file:///C:/SomePath/SomeFolder?select=*.xml')">
    <xsl:message expand-text="yes">Processing file {.}</xsl:message>
    <xsl:source-document href="{.}" streamable="yes">
      <xsl:value-of select="descendant::country[@name = 'Country_Name'][1]"/>
    </xsl:source-document>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

To use streaming, you need Saxon EE; you might want to request a trial license from Saxonica if you want to check/test whether that approach performs better than traditional XSLT 3.

I am not sure, however, the posted code stops processing the file after finding that first element; would need to test/check; there is an `xsl:iterate`/`xsl:break` where Saxon EE I think does an early exit.

Following the documentation at https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/streaming/partial-reading.html I have tried code along the lines of

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

   <xsl:param name="uri" as="xs:string" expand-text="no">file:///C:/SomePath/SomeFolder?select=*.xml</xsl:param>

   <xsl:param name="items-to-select" as="xs:integer" select="1"/>
     
   <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
      <xsl:for-each select="uri-collection($uri)">
        <xsl:message expand-text="yes">Processing file {.}</xsl:message>
        <xsl:source-document href="{.}" streamable="yes">
          <xsl:iterate select="outermost(descendant::country[@name = 'Country_Name'])">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:if test="position() eq $items-to-select">
              <xsl:break/>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:iterate>
        </xsl:source-document>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:output method="text" item-separator="&#10;"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and it passes the streamability analysis and also indicates an early exit (although only once when I process three files (without the `-t` option); indeed three times if I use the `-t` option and process three files: this is with 11.5 EE; I have now also tested with 12.0 EE and it outputs `SXQP0001  The input file has not been read to completion` for each processed file without using the `-t` option).

So that would mean, if you have files where that element is early in all or lots of documents, that parsing should be abandoned once the element has been found.

In some simple tests it looks as if a streamed, early exit solution run through Saxon 12.0 EE is faster than the unstreamed one if files are sufficiently large and the element to look for is at some point early in each document.

Comment: Thankyou Martin for your understanding of my code mistake, I would be really interested in your analysis of `xsl:iterate/xsl:break` does have a marked improvement in processing improvement.

I have reached out the the good people a Saxonica to request a trial of the EE version.

Comment: @michaelbinks, see my edit, with `xsl:iterate/xsl:break` when using streaming you can get an "early exit" by the parser meaning, if you parse a lots of documents where that element can be found parsing only e.g. 10 % of the document I would expect that to show in performance tests. But in the end you will need to check on your own.

Comment: @michaelbinks, were you able to test the approach? Did you achieve any noticeable or even important performance improvement for your whole set of "circa 600K XML files"?

Answer (score 0):

Normally I advise people that streaming doesn't make execution faster, its purpose is to reduce memory usage. It's possible that the "early exit" could make a difference, but only measurement will tell. With documents under 100K, I believe that quite a lot of the XML parsing cost is initialisation of the parse, so an early exit might not save as much as one hopes.

With this kind of workload the biggest gain from using Saxon-EE might come from parallel processing of the input documents. The `collection()` function under Saxon-EE does parallel parsing automatically, but combining this with streaming might take a bit more thought.